# RestartSec vs RestartUSec in systemd

Tags: systemd

I have been working, recently, on `CentOS` and `openSUSE` systems. I found that configuring the `sshd.service`, I see:

systemctl show sshd.service

This shows `RestartUSec` rather than `RestartSec` as one of my parameters. The `man` documentation doesn't discuss `RestartUSec`. Is it the same as `RestartSec`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [this bug report reported in 2013](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1018335), `RestartUSec` is a low-level interface value (mostly for tools), whereas `RestartSec` is the high-level value [that is documented in the `systemd.service` man page.](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) There is no difference as far as I can tell between the two except that one only uses microseconds and the other is more free-form.

Comment: Understood. So is it fine to just use RestartSec without any interference from the RestartUSec?

Comment: Yes. I wouldn't worry about directives not found in the documentation as they are not guaranteed and (unlikely) subject to change. From some more reading, apparently `RestartUSec` is freeform too, so there's literally no difference between the two except for the interpretation of untyped values.